# bootstrap collapse menu has 2 rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I am building this website
[torgoborudovanie.com](http://www.torgoborudovanie.com/)

I have a collapsing navbar build with bootstrap.But when I try to resize the window I get something like this : [image]

As you can see (and you can actually try it ) nav bar now has 2 lines and it looks wired (the actual problem is that it looks like this on Iphone and Ipad) Then you can resize it a little bit more and it gets collapsed as I want.[image]

You can see the code by simply viewing html code in  developer tools.
So I will not post it here to make qustion clean and small.But if you want I can post the code here too=)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this (quite shitty to be fair  workaround)
On page load if I have window.width less than 1200px I just hide long text.

```
function hideSlogan() {
    if($(window).width() <1200) {$('.slogan').hide()} 
};
hideSlogan();
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the CSS rules starting at the **MOBILE NAV** comment; these are the rules you can adjust to make the navbar collapse at different breakpoints.

On a sidenote, there is one extra, broken list tag in the nav and with the positioning of **Надежный партнер - качественные решения!** inside your **navbar-collapse** div you'll the following behavior:

If you expand the menu when it's in the mobile and then expand the viewport your `navbar` will revert to the **line-height: 60px** unless the browser is refreshed. Might not matter but since you're trying to change the collapse breakpoint it's worth mentioning.

**I also moved the inline styles with the rest of the CSS Rules.

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400, 700, 800);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Baskerville:400italic);
 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
body {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  color: #42413e;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
/* BOOTSTRAP MODIFICATION */

.navbar-right a .btn-orange {
  margin-top: -5px;
}
.btn-orange {
  background: #f27242;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.btn-orange:hover {
  background: #e16a3e;
  color: white;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.navbar.navbar-default {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #e7e7e7;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #f27242;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #ccc;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-right {
  padding-top: 5px
}
.navbar-default li.dropdown a {
  color: black;
}
.navbar-default span.head-title {
  line-height: 60px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-right .dropdown-menu {
  right: auto;
  left: 0;
}
.navbar-right li.contact-info a {
  color: #42413e;
}
/****MOBILE NAVBAR******/

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .custom-navbar .navbar-header {
    float: none;
  }
  .custom-navbar .navbar-left,
  .custom-navbar .navbar-right {
    float: none !important;
  }
  .custom-navbar .navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
  }
  .custom-navbar .navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  .custom-navbar.navbar-fixed-top {
    top: 0;
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
  }
  .custom-navbar .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;
  }
  .custom-navbar .navbar-nav {
    float: none!important;
    margin-top: 7.5px;
  }
  .custom-navbar .navbar-nav > li {
    float: none;
  }
  .custom-navbar .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .custom-navbar .collapse.in {
    display: block !important;
  }
  .custom-navbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .custom-navbar .navbar-brand {
    height: 55px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default custom-navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Переключить навигацию</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="http://www.torgoborudovanie.com/assets/img/logo1.png" width="140">
      </a>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"><span class="head-title">Надежный партнер - качественные решения!</span>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Каталог <span class="caret"></span></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="stellazhi">Стеллажи</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="torg-mebel">Торговая мебель</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="telezhki-korzini">Тележки и корзины</a>

            </li>
            <li> <a href="kass-boxes">Кассовые боксы</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="holod-oborudovanie">Холодильное оборудование</a>

            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="delivery">Условия доставки</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="contact-info">
          <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-phone "></i> 8 (343) 3448090</a>

        </li>
        <li class="contact-info">
          <a href="mailto:info@optimagp.ru"> <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> info@optimagp.ru</a>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#f">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-orange" type="button">Заказать звонок</button>
          </a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this on monday cause tomorrow I will be away from laptop))) And today is too late=)

Answer (score -1):

you need to change your breakpoint, when the navbar gets collapsed...

so for example, this should work:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    .collapse {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
     .collapse {
          display: none;
      }
      .navbar-toggle {
         display: block;
      }
}
```

because it floats (because its so long) after 1200px width...

** sorry, i made a mistake... try it now :) **

Comment: [link to test page](http://www.torgoborudovanie.com/test.html) Here as you can see I've lost logo and also I get some retina display errors ( I can delete retina library so one problem less)

Comment: Still not=( See test.html again. Now it shows data-togle but doesn't hide and doesn't open on data-toggle